# Java perlin noise

Tags: java, actionscript-3, perlin-noise

I need to make perlin noise like in [AS3.0](http://www.houseofthead.com/blog/flash-as3-perlin-noise-explained-and-demonstrated-part-1/):

```
bitmapData.perlinNoise(baseX, baseY, numOctaves, 
randomSeed, stitch, fractalNoise, grayScale, offsets);
```

It's seamless noise:

[image]

I found a lot of material about it, but I can't make it like in my as3.0 image. Java code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Noise extends JPanel{

    public static int octaves = 4;
    public static int size =  128;
    public static float[][][] noise = new float[size][size][octaves];
    public static float[][] perlinnoise = new float[size][size];

    public static float p = (float) 1/4;

    public static Random gen = new Random();

    public static float GenerateNoise() {
        return gen.nextFloat();
    }

    public static float SmoothNoise(int x, int y, int z) {
        try{
            float corners = (noise[x - 1][y - 1][z] + noise[x + 1][y - 1][z] + noise[x - 1][y + 1][z] + noise[x + 1][y + 1][z]) / 16;
            float sides = (noise[x - 1][y][z] + noise[x + 1][y][z] + noise[x][y - 1][z] + noise[x][y + 1][z]) / 8;
            float center = noise[x][y][z] / 4;
            return corners + sides + center;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static float InterpolatedNoise(float x, float y, int pX, int pY, int pZ) {
        int intX = (int) x;
        int intY = (int) y;
        float fracX = x - intX;
        float fracY = y - intY;
        float v1 = SmoothNoise(pX, pY, pZ);
        float v2 = SmoothNoise(pX + 1, pY, pZ);
        float v3 = SmoothNoise(pX, pY + 1, pZ);
        float v4 = SmoothNoise(pX + 1, pY + 1, pZ);
        float i1 = Interpolate(v1, v2, fracX);
        float i2 = Interpolate(v3, v4, fracX);
        return Interpolate(i1, i2, fracY);
    }

    public static float Interpolate(float a, float b, float x) {
        float ft = (float) (x * 3.1415927);
        float f = (float) ((1 - Math.cos(ft)) * 0.5);
        return (float) (a * (1 - f) + b * f);
    }

    public static float Perlin2D(float x, float y, int posX, int posY, int posZ) {
        float total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {
            double f = Math.pow(2, i);
            double a = Math.pow(p, i);
            total = (float) (total + InterpolatedNoise((float)(x * f), (float)(y * f), posX, posY, posZ) * a);
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(int z = 0; z < octaves; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    noise[x][y][z] = GenerateNoise();
                }
            }
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < octaves; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    perlinnoise[x][y] = Perlin2D(x / (size - 1), y / (size - 1), x, y, z) / octaves;
                }
            }
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Perlin Noise");
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new Noise());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(perlinnoise[x][y], perlinnoise[x][y], perlinnoise[x][y]));
                g.fillRect(x * 2, y * 2, 2, 2);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Help please!

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, the Perlin noise does not use pseudo-random generator, it uses a function that takes an argument and returns predefined value for that argument, but when argument shifts by 1, the value jumps almost randomly. Check [the sources](http://www.mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html#noise) for the permutation formulae, the `init()` method makes a permutation that then is used to make the entire noise.